# accessing each element in a numpy array

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, pygame

I'm attempting to remove stray white pixels from an alpha channel mask by looking at the adjacent pixels, but have been getting TypeEror: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
I made an array using pygame.surfarray: 
`alphachannel3d = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(alphachannel)`
then attempt to step through it and change pixel values from white to black: 
  `if (alphachannel3d[x] == (0, 0, 0)) & (alphachannel3d[x + 3] == (255, 255, 255)) & (alphachannel3d[x -3]==(255, 255, 255)):
    alphachannel3d[x] = (255, 255, 255)`

Here is the loop:

```
x=1

while 1:

  count = x
  print 'count is', count

  print 'waiting 5 seconds'
  pygame.time.wait(5000)


  img = cam.get_image()

  imgarray = pygame.PixelArray(img)

  alphachannelarray = basearray.compare(imgarray, distance=0.09, weights=(0.01, 0.01, 0.01))

  alphachannel = alphachannelarray.make_surface()

  alphachannel3d = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(alphachannel)


  if (alphachannel3d[x] == (0, 0, 0)) & (alphachannel3d[x + 3] == (255, 255, 255)) & (alphachannel3d[x -3]==(255, 255, 255)):
    alphachannel3d[x] = (255, 255, 255)

  alphachannel = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(alphachannel3d)
  srfcScreen.blit(alphachannel, (0,0))
  print 'screen blitted'

  pygame.display.flip()
  print 'display flipped'

  x = x+1
```

Comment: What is x? Can you include the code loop you're actually using (or a cutdown version of it)? Also, I suggest seeing if you can use synthetic numpy only data to trigger the same behaviour.

Comment: x is a counter, stepping through the pixels in the array. I'll edit above to include the loop.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback from your exception? That should help us see where it's coming from.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/surfarrayused.py", line 75, in <module>
    if (alphachannel3d[x] == (0, 0, 0)) & (alphachannel3d[x + 3] == (255, 255, 255)):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @TfromNYC Surely that's the answer you need? "Use a.any() or a.all()".

Comment: @TfromNYC Also, that's a different exception to the one you said you were getting in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I'm going to give the following speculative answer (without testing it):

```
if np.all(alphachannel3d[x] == (0, 0, 0)) & np.all(alphachannel3d[x + 3] == (255, 255, 255)) & np.all(alphachannel3d[x -3]==(255, 255, 255)):
    alphachannel3d[x] = (255, 255, 255)
```